# Wordpress Ajax response has html comments

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I am using a wordpress contact-form-7 in Ajax mode when a request is submitted the response is returned but the response has HTML comments included. the breaks the JS code.

Any one help me please. following is the response when I submit button a comment is included that says <-- w: nobody -->

```
{"mailSent":false,"into":"#wpcf7-f85-o1","captcha":null,"message":"Validation errors occurred. Please confirm the fields and submit it again.","invalids":[{"into":"span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.your-name","message":"Please fill the required field.","idref":null},{"into":"span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.your-email","message":"Please fill the required field.","idref":null}]}<!-- w: nobody-->
```

Comment: Does `<!-- w: nobody-->` appear on other pages? It's probably coming from one of your themes or plugins. Try switching themes and deactivating plugins to find which one.

Comment: Yes, I used a different theme and disabled all my plugins while activated just contact form 7 still face the issue.

Comment: You could try re-installing WordPress.

Comment: I do not want to re-install every thing...If some one has already faced the issue please respond here.

Comment: Check if this output is on all pages or just AJAX pages (i.e. view source of home page). Also, WordPress can reinstall just the WordPress core.

Comment: Yes, I solved the by installing the wordpress core.. it worked thanks.